# Create CSV from specific columns in another CSV using shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I have a CSV file with several thousand lines, and I need to take some of the columns in that file to create another CSV file to use for import to a database.

I'm not in shape with shell scripting anymore, is there anyone who can help with pointing me in the correct direction?

I have a bash script to read the source file but when I try to print the columns I want to a new file it just doesn't work.

```
while IFS=, read symbol tr_ven tr_date sec_type sec_name name
do
    echo "$name,$name,$symbol" >> output.csv
done < test.csv
```

Above is the code I have. Out of the 6 columns in the original file, I want to build a CSV with "column6, column6, collumn1"

The test CSV file is like this:

```
Symbol,Trading Venue,Trading Date,Security Type,Security Name,Company Name
AAAIF,Grey Market,22/01/2015,Fund,,Alternative Investment Trust
AAALF,Grey Market,22/01/2015,Ordinary Shares,,Aareal Bank AG
AAARF,Grey Market,22/01/2015,Ordinary Shares,,Aluar Aluminio Argentino S.A.I.C.
```

What am I doing wrong with my script? Or, is there an easier - and faster - way of doing this?

#### Edit

These are the real headers:

```
Symbol,US Trading Venue,Trading Date,OTC Tier,Caveat Emptor,Security Type,Security Class,Security Name,REG_SHO,Rule_3210,Country of Domicile,Company Name
```

I'm trying to get the last column, which is number 12, but it always comes up empty.

Comment: the snippet looks fine to me. I even tested it and worked as expected. You can consider using this awk, though, a bit more straight forward: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $6,$6,$1}' test.csv > output.csv`

Comment: You know what, I also found a solution with AWK and tried it, didn't work... but I just tried yours and it did! The other AWK solution I found was like this (only with different columns): `awk -F, '{getline f1 <"test.csv" ;print f1,$3,$4}' OFS=, output.csv`

Comment: Care to write your solution as an answer to accept it?

Comment: Sure! This `getline` usage is quite unnecessary, so throw away that snippet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippet looks and works fine to me, maybe you have some weird characters in the file or it is coming from a DOS environment (use `dos2unix` to "clean" it!). Also, you can make use of `read -r` to prevent strange behaviours with backslashes.

But let's see how can `awk` solve this even faster:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $6,$6,$1}' test.csv >> output.csv
```

#### Explanation

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` this sets the input and output field separators to the comma. Alternatively, you can say `-F=","`, `-F,` or pass it as a variable with `-v FS=","`. The same applies for `OFS`.
- `{print $6,$6,$1}` prints the 6th field twice and then the 1st one. Note that using `print`, every comma-separated parameter that you give will be printed with the `OFS` that was previously set. Here, with a comma.

Comment: Ok, I used the above CSV sample to simplify, and it does work using the command you said, but when I modify it to the real file, it does't.. these are my headers:

Comment: I updated the question, with the correct headers and the problem that the very last column always comes up empty... any idea what I'm doing wrong? This is my final awk command: awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $12,$6,$1}' test.csv > output.csv

Comment: It is difficult to say from the input. But if you want to print the last field, you can use `{print $NF}` in awk. As `NF` refers to the number of fields, `$NF` contains the last one. So for example, do write the following and check if the file really contains 12 fields: `awk '{print NF}'`  and expect 12. Otherwise, check what is the 12th field saying `awk '{print $NF}'`. Always with the `BEGIN{}` block, of course

Comment: Ok, it was newlines that were acting up... I couldn't use dos2unix on my mac, I ran cat test.csv | col -b > x.csv and after that your awk ran great!

Comment: Thanks fedorqui, I will save this awk command for future reference :)