# Unix shell script - select columns from csv file based on headers in another csv file (reposted with minimal reproducible example)

Tags: shell, csv, unix, awk

Reposting this question as previous answer didn't work, due to lack of minimal reproducible example (mea culpa). Sorry if this is basic but I cannot get it to work, and have spent many hours trying.

Please see previous question I posted earlier:
[Unix shell script select columns in csv file based on headers from another csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76531447/unix-shell-script-select-columns-in-csv-file-based-on-headers-from-another-csv-f)

I created a csv header file, where each row in the header file is the name of the column I want. In the data_file.csv itself, the first row appears as follows, with each of the column headers in the first row, with the data enclosed in quotes:

```
echo $(head -n 1 data_file.csv)
"eid","132421-0.0","132422-0.0","132423-0.0", ...
```

The header file I created looks like this, with each of the column headers as a row without quotes.

```
eid
24500-0.0
24503-0.0
24503-1.0
4526-0.0
4526-1.0
```

Notice no quotes. If I try to add quotes (manually) to the headers.csv file, and then using $cat again, I get three lots of quotes on each of the header rows (don't know why).

```
"""eid"""
"""24500-0.0"""
"""24500-1.0"""
"""24503-0.0"""
"""24503-1.0"""
"""4526-0.0"""
"""4526-1.0"""
```

All I want to do is extract the 20 columns with the headers as listed in the headers.csv file from the enormous data_file.csv (which has 28,000 columns). Then I can load those into R and away I go.

The data itself is a mix of characters and numerics, with each field enclosed in quotes.

@glenn_jackman suggested the following solution but I didn't point out the quotes:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","}
    NR == FNR {wanted[$0] = 1; next}
    FNR == 1 {
        ncol = 0
        for (i = 1; i <= NR; i++)
            if ($i in wanted)
                columns[++ncol] = i
    }
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= ncol; i++)
            printf "%s%s", $columns[i], OFS
        print ""
    }
' headers.csv data_file.csv > selected_data_file.csv
```

Therefore this fails and I get a blank selected_data_file.csv.

The output I am looking for is:

```
$ cat selected_data_file.csv
"eid", "24500-0.0", "24503-0.0", "24503-1.0", "4526-0.0", "4526-1.0"
"AB1","1","a","0","1.2",""
```

with the same number of rows as data_file.csv.

Don't know how to make it any clearer or more reproducible than that ... very many thanks for any help.

Comment: can any of the header or data fields contain commas? or do commas ***only*** show up as field delimiters?  also, can any fields contain embedded linefeeds?

Comment: what is the output from running `awk --version`?

Comment: your one-line input sample shows no spaces after the comma; the header line in your desired output shows a space after the comma, but no spaces (after the comma) in the data line; please confirm a) if spaces (after commas) exist in the input file and b) if you really want spaces (after commas) in the output but only for the header line; while this may sound like a nitpick, these inconsistencies add to the complexity of the code (assuming you're not using a tool geared specifically for processing csv files)

Comment: if you're using `GNU awk` (aka `gawk`) you may be interested in parsing by field pattern (as opposed to parsing by delimiter); see [splitting by content](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) for more details; here in stackoverflow.com you can also run a search on `[awk] FPAT` for plenty of examples

Comment: @markp-fuso thank you for taking a look. The headers do not contain commas. Unfortunately some of the data fields do, from a close inspection, but I don't know which ones, and they are all enclosed within quotation marks

Comment: The output of running awk --version is: GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0)

Comment: fwiw, a minimal example would consist of, say, 5-6 columns, 3-4 lines (including header), samples of fields that are indicative of your actual data file (eg, fields including commas, fields not wrapped in quotes, spaces around the comma/delimiter), and the expected output would be a subset of those 5-6 columns

Comment: @markp-fuso (a) there are no spaces after the comma in the data line. (b) I hadn't noticed the spaces in the header line but I don't need them, I just need an output csv file with only ~20 columns that can be read into R or Python as a much smaller dataframe. I can't use csvkit as I have no admin rights on the server and asking for new software takes weeks.

Comment: The problem with the datafile is that it's enormous (UK Biobank data), 28,000 columns and 500,000 rows. Each column of the csv file is held as text enclosed in quotation marks. e.g. "1", "","1.2","a line of text".

Comment: @markp-fuso I don't think the csv file contains any embedded line feeds. I thought the easiest way to handle it would be to return the column index based on the first row of the datafile (i.e. the header row), and then simply to print the column at that index to a file (which is I think what glenn_jackman's code does).

Comment: I'm not precious about using awk! I've never used it before, and once I have this datafile I'll probably never have to use it again :-)

Comment: Thank you for your points on the minimal reproducible example too.

Comment: If I understand the problem right, `csvcut` from the `csvkit` package should be pretty easy to make work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain a [mcve] so we can help you. See [@markp-fuso's earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76532716/unix-shell-script-select-columns-from-csv-file-based-on-headers-in-another-csv#comment134941574_76532716) for what;s missing from your question.

Comment: `bash -c 'mlr --csv cut -f "$(echo $(<headerfile)|tr " " ,)"' <in.csv >out.csv`

Comment: `bash -c 'csvcut -c "$(echo $(<headerfile)|tr " " ,)"' <in.csv >out.csv`

Comment: Thank you everyone. I can't use csvkit but will come back to the minimal reproducible example to see if I can improve on what's there. However I don't know the content of all 28,000 columns of data.

Comment: I am not sure why this was downvoted, as it's a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: You've been asked twice now to provide a [mcve] as described by @markp-fuso in a comment above -  say, 5-6 columns, 3-4 lines (including header), samples of fields that are indicative of your actual data file (eg, fields including commas, fields not wrapped in quotes, spaces around the comma/delimiter), and the expected output would be a subset of those 5-6 columns. Without that we have nothing that clearly demonstrates your problem and nothing to test a potential solution against. See [ask] and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples of reasonable questions

Comment: Not providing an adequate [mcve] ,despite [@glennjackman requesting one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76531447/unix-shell-script-select-columns-in-csv-file-based-on-headers-from-another-csv-f#comment134938921_76531692) after he answered, is what caused [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76531447/1745001) to get downvoted and only have 1 person attempt to answer it.

Comment: Note that `wanted[$0] = 1` can just be `wanted[$0]`. In Awk, an associative array key doesn't have to have a value; just by mentioning the key it is added to the array. E.g. after executing `foo["bar"];`, the test `if ("bar" in foo) ...` will be true.

Answer (score 1):

You state in a comment that you are working with a UK Biobank dataset. [Biobank](https://biobank.ctsu.ox.ac.uk/) provides a conversion utility `ukbconv` for Windows and linux: https://biobank.ctsu.ox.ac.uk/crystal/download.cgi

According to [this pdf](https://www.ndph.ox.ac.uk/files/research/ukb_dataguide_download_lc_v0-6_23nov2020.pdf) and [the official documentation](https://biobank.ctsu.ox.ac.uk/%7Ebbdatan/Data_Access_Guide_v3.1.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A283%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C54.4499%2C778.0999%2C0%5D), given a list of field numbers in a text file, the command to directly extract the relevant columns from the original file into a format suitable for R is:

```
ukbconv dataset.enc_ukb r -ifield_list.txt
```

---

The documentation distinguishes between "fields" and "columns":

> For example, assume we just want to extract fields 31, 20204 and 40000 from our dataset and convert it to csv format. We create a text file called `field_list.txt` with the contents:
>
> ```
> 31
> 20204
> 40000
> ```
>
> and place it into the same folder as `ukbconv`. We then run the command:
>
> ```
> ukbconv ukb23456.enc_ukb csv -ifield_list.txt
> ```
>
> The resulting output will only contain the eid column and columns for all instance and array combinations for Data-Fields 31, 20204 and 40000 (assuming those Data-Fields are present in the `.enc_ukb` file).
>
> To assist with preparing the file giving the list of required fields, `ukbconv` outputs the file
> named `field.ukb` each time it is run which lists all the available fields associated with
> the dataset. This can be edited to identify the particular fields which are to be included in
> or excluded from the subset.

It also discusses "instance and array indices" and notes that in the case of csv:

> column headers are in the format `F-I.A`
> where `F` is the Data-Field number, `I` is the instance index and `A` is the array index

That looks like the header format from your question, so it may be that by using `ukbconv` you will end up with more data than you asked for (ie. extra columns). This may or not be a problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions/Understandings derived from the question and OP's comments:

- all fields (including header fields) are enclosed in double quotes
- fields are separated by commas and possibly spaces on either side of the comma
- fields may contain commas
- fields do not contain embedded linefeeds

Making up some sample data based on (above) assumptions:

```
$ cat headers.csv
eid
24503-1.0
4526-1.0

$ cat data_file.csv
"eid","24500-0.0", "24503-0.0", "24503-1.0","4526-0.0", "4526-1.0"
"AB1","1","a","0,111","1.2",""
"CD2","2","b","9","","-123,be"
```

One `GNU awk` (for `FPAT` support):

```
awk '
BEGIN   { FPAT = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" }                   # define field patterns

        # remove following block if we do NOT have to worry about white space before/after the comma delimiter

        { for ( i=1;i<=NF;i++ )                             # for all fields ...
              gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",$i)     # strip leading/trailing white space
        }

FNR==NR { hdr["\"" $1 "\""]                                 # 1st file: populate array of headers
          next
        }

FNR==1  { for ( i=1;i<=NF;i++ )                             # 2nd file: process header fields
              if ( $i in hdr )                              # if in our hdr[] array then 
                 cols[++colcnt] = i                         # populate array of columns making note of their order
        }
        { for ( i=1;i<=colcnt;i++ )                         # 2nd file: for each data line loop through list of desired columns and print to stdout
              printf "%s%s", $(cols[i]), (i<colcnt ? "," : ORS)
        }
' headers.csv data_file.csv
```

This generates:

```
"eid","24503-1.0","4526-1.0"
"AB1","0,111",""
"CD2","9","-123,be"
```